# Rails app on heroku not allowing logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm having issues with my rails app when i deploy it to heroku. I'm using steam-omniauth. The log out function works correctly on my machine, but won't work when deployed. Clicking the logout link transfers me to a 404 screen and this error message in the log. looks like its trying to use 'get' for some reason. I've also made sure to rake my db, and pushed the latest versions through to heroku. I'm kind of out of ideas.

at=info method=GET path="/logout" host=warm-sands-60002.herokuapp.com request_id=d01b9d02-238f-41f6-a894-0e74bf64a1c0 fwd="98.169.0.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https`

my destroy action in the sessions_controller

```
def destroy
  if current_user
    session.delete(:user_id)
    flash[:success] = "Goodbye!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

sessions helper

```
def current_user
    if cookies[:remember_token].present?
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end
end
```

routes

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: :all


delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

and my logout link

`<li class="nav-item"><%= link_to 'Log Out', logout_path, method: :delete %></li>`

if theres anything i can provide let me know. this is pretty frustrating.

Comment: make sure you're including `rails_ujs` in your javascript bundle; alternatively, you can set the `config.sign_out_via` to `[:get, :delete]` in devise.rb

Answer (score 1):

Per your log message, the logout action is being submitted with a `GET` instead of a `DELETE` method. It looks like your logout link is using UJS.

If it's working locally in dev, but not when deployed, it's probably because your javascript isn't compiling correctly, served correctly, or being loaded correctly. Look at your browser developer console to see if anything is being logged there.

Comment: Sure enough, I'm getting 404's on the application.js file. I'm not sure how to rectify it either.

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .`


that's my application.js file. I also added it in the assets.rb file, no luck.

Comment: @JosephHarskamp You're probably better off asking a separate question about why you're getting a 404 for your application.js.